# Limitations with Xamarin related to access to device-specific capabilities (like NFC, Bluetooth)?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

Currently, I find myself in the position of defending Xamarin's ability to access and control device specific capabilities and peripherals (like using NFC, Bluetooth, etc.) and I was wondering if you could help enlighten me and provide me with some reference material to use to support my hypothesis. My hypothesis is that using Xamarin to access and control device peripherals is no different than using Java on Android and Objective-C/Swift on iOS. There might be a very slight performance difference, but nothing noticeable. Is this hypothesis correct? If so, where can I find supporting evidence? If not, where am I wrong? Are there limitations I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

You're right. Beside the tooling what Xamarin provide to it's customers are bindings: managed API over the native API that the OS (either iOS or Android) offers.

Xamarin provides (with it's products) the bindings for OS API and it also ships the tools for customers to create *custom* bindings on their own (or 3rd parties) native libraries.

Some platforms (or versions) of an OS might have their own limits but they will be identical across the languages you use.